# Aligning banner under IE

Tags: internet-explorer, css-position

I wanted to pasted a banner in my header-logo. Under Chrome/FF and Safari it worked out very well, but under IE i did not manage to position the banner correctly.

I tested position:absolute; or position:relative and many other variables but nothing helps. Who can help me?

**Code in Stylesheet relating to positioning:**

```
#container{
    position:absolute;
}
p.header2{
    position:relative;
    left:235px;
    top:3px;
}
```

**Code in website relating to banner:**

```
<div id="container">
    <p class="header2">
        .........banner code................
    </p>
</div>
```

Screenshots:

[banner](http://www.cognacfans.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/IE-Banner.jpg)
[image: Banner]

[header](http://www.cognacfans.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/FF-Safari-header.jpg)
[image: Header]

Comment: Would you be so kind to share the version of internet explorer it is failing in?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#container{
   position:relative;
}
p.header2{
 position:absolute;
 left:235px;
 top:3px;
}
```